# Does PostgreSQL support Active-Active Clustering with DRBD?

Tags: postgresql, high-availability

We use PostgreSQL 9.3 in our application. We want to setup PostgreSQL active-active clustering with DRBD. I google it and see a lot of resource about active-passive.

Does PostgreSQL support Active-Active Clustering with DRBD?

Comment: If you are looking for horizontal scaling, projects like Postgres-XC and Postgres-XL look promising (they implement a shared nothing architecture on top of Postgres)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL does not support active/active clustering with DRBD.

PostgreSQL does not support any form of shared-storage clustering in any way - active/active, active/passive, or otherwise.

It's rather implausible to support shared storage clustering with the architecture in PostgreSQL. Lots of things would need to change. In particular, Pg couldn't lazily write buffers to disk anymore, which would be brutal for performance.

You'll need to use replication. You can use read-replicas (with a few limitations) that way.

There's no support for multi-master, nor is there any support for auto-relaying write queries to the master from a replica. Some people use PgPool-II for routing queries, though it also has some significant limitations.

(I'm involved in work on bi-directional replication, which seeks to offer another alternative, but it's very much alpha. See [BDR on the PostgreSQL wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide))